# Как в фильтр задать св-во привязка к элементам?

Tags: битрикс

Доброго времени суток!

Как задать фильтр для компонента по свойству привязка к элементу?
Вывел массив arResult, в нем нашел массив [CITY], нужное свойство [VALUE], пробовал написать так:

```
$arrFilter = array("PROPERTY_CITY_VALUE"=>$userCity);
```

но видимо что то не правильно. 
Фильтр в настройках компонента включен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_CITY" => $userCity/*тут должно быть число — ID элемента*/);
```

Comment: `$arrFilter = array("=PROPERTY_CITY" => 70);` 70 это значение одного из городов, не сработало, так же выводит все

Comment: global $arrFilter; сделали?